# Time complexity of median of medians algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, median-of-medians

Hello I am taking Introduction to algorithm class this semeseter. However I have some problem in calculating time complexity of median of medians algorithm ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians)).
I'm wondering how to get `T(n)<=10cn from T(n)<=T(0.2n)+T(0.7n)+cn..`

I think I cannot apply mater theorem to the expression above and wikipedia says I should use induction but I don't know How..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using induction.
Assume for less than or equal `n` we have `T(n) <= 10*c*n` (we know the base of induction is true for equal or less than `T(10)` as they are constant and we can use large enough value for `c`). Now we want to prove this for `T(n + 1)`. We know `T(n + 1) <= T(0.2(n + 1)) + T(0.7( n + 1)) + c(n+1)`. From the assumption of the induction as `0.2(n + 1)` and `0.7(n+1)` is less than `n` (for `n > 10`), `T(0.2(n + 1)) <= 10*c*0.2(n + 1)` and `T(0.7(n + 1)) <= 10*c*0.7(n + 1)`. Therefore, `T(n+1) <= 2*c(n+1) + 7*c(n+1) + n*c = 10*c*n`. The proof is completed!

Comment: would you please explain me the induction way?

Comment: @JiseopHan The answer is updated. If it works for you, please accept it as a solution.

Comment: I think there is calculation error in the equation above for akra-bazzi. T(x) = O(x * (1 + integral_1^{x}(x/x^2)=T(x) = O(x * (1 + integral_1^{x}(1/x)=O(x*(1+c*logx))=O(xlogx) isn't it?