# Finding block median in median of medians algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, median, median-of-medians

I know that formula for the median of medians algorithm is :
`T(n)<= T(0.7n)+T(0.2n)+O(n)` and `O(n)` came from finding median of each block(size of 5), and I'm wondering why It takes O(n) to find median of each block.. that sound like finding median of one block takes `O(1)`. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size of each block is constant (`5`). Hence, Finding the median of each block is in `O(1)` (sort the block in `O(1)` and take the mid index as a median). Therefore, finding the median of all blocks is in `O(n)`. And after that find the median of the median of each block which is answered in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52811311/3768871).

Comment: I can't understand why it takes O(1)time if the block size is constant. would you please explain me?

Comment: @JiseopHan sort the block in O(1) and take the mid index as a median of the block.

Comment: @OmG How can we sort the array size of 5 with O(1)time?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog it is for finding the median of the median. The complexity of this part is found in `c*n`.

Comment: @JiseopHan the complexity of the sort is `n log n`. Hence, you can do it in `5 log 5` whcih is constant

Comment: Now I understood fully. Thanks so much again!!